# Managing multiple segments in template routes

Tags: url, segments, template-routes

For one of my templates, I need two extra segments.

If I have the following in template routes, the page only loads if there is 1 segment.

```
/gallery/{alpha_dash}
```

If I add the following, it fails:

```
/gallery/{alpha_dash}/{alpha_dash}
```

The following works for two or one extra segment, but not just /gallery.

```
/gallery/{a:alpha_dash}/{b:alpha_dash}
```

Can anyone explain how I can have it work for all segments:

```
/gallery
/gallery/...
/gallery/.../...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `segments required?` flag in the template manager is set to "no", then your longest route (i.e. `/gallery/{alpha_dash}/{alpha_dash}`) should work for all your test cases.  If it doesn't, try turning the two `alpha_dash` instances into separate variables - e.g. `/gallery/{a:alpha_dash}/{b:alpha_dash}`

Comment: Hi Gavin. Segments required is set to 'no'. As I explain in my question, I already tried /gallery/{alpha_dash}/{alpha_dash} and /gallery/{a:alpha_dash}/{b:alpha_dash} with neither working. Am I to understand that this means there is a bug?

Comment: Hi ccdavies - you didn't say in your posting that you had tried setting the segments required to 'no'...  Based on the documentation here the long form should work https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/urls/template_routes.html